# "User not found" for Graph API request in the Azure enterprise app security group with client credentials auth flow

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**Design**

[image: design overview]

**Goal**

Get calendar events for a given user.

**Requirements**

1. Application should have access to the MS Graph API.
2. Application should act like a daemon/background process and not depend on user's login.
3. Application should have access to the minimal number of users' data in the Azure Active Directory (AAD).
4. Application should be able to fetch user's calendar events and create them.

**Implementation / Setup**

- to fulfill (1) Azure (Enterprise) App was created as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal).
- to enable (2) client credentials flow was used with the setup of `application permissions`
- to meet (3) a `security group` - as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mail-enabled-security-groups?view=exchserver-2019) - was created with a limited number of users with the related `policy` that included related permissions (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)). The group was later connected to the app following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles) instruction.
- to implement (4) the `Calendar.Read` and `Calendar.ReadWrite` as required by the actions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) were added to the policy mentioned in the previous setup step.

**Testing**

Two HTTP requests were used: one to get the token and another to read events.

1. token request from the `Identity Platform`

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--data-raw 'client_id=<APPLICATION_TOKEN>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=<APPLICATION_SECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Upon inspection of the token [here](https://jwt.io/) I see that it contains required permissions:

```json
  "roles": [
    "Calendars.Read",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite"
  ]
```

2. fetch request of the calendar events from `Graph API`

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<USER_ID>/calendar/events' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>'
```

results in the following error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "User not found",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-02-08T08:25:39",
      "request-id": "bfaca1f9-e79b-491c-8d75-5a62317e299b",
      "client-request-id": "bfaca1f9-e79b-491c-8d75-5a62317e299b"
    }
  }
}
```

The user id is from my account that I found in the Azure Active Directory details of the Azure Tenant. I double-checked that after adding other users.

**Before-asking investigation**

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/471424/graph-api-get-calendar-result-in-resource-not-foun.html) issue looks closest to my case as it uses the client credentials auth flow. But it uses global permissions for all users in the AAD, while we use more fine-grained approach with a `security group`. It also shows a different error `"Resource could not be discovered."` versus `"User not found"` in my case.

Comment: The work accounts usually have 2 formats, `firstname.lastname@company.com` and `employeeid@company.com`. Try both of these formats.

Comment: In my request I use id: `ttps://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<USER_ID>/calendar/events`. How do you suggest to use email?

Comment: at the place of `<USER_ID>`, I have used same.

Comment: ok, then I understood you correctly. I tried both and get a different error: `The requested user 'xxx' is invalid.`. I even tried `employeeid@company.onmicrosoft.com` and `firstname.lastname@company.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: I found the reason. It was a missing global permission. It turned out that the security group only restricted the permissions. Can I answer my own question this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Version**
I was missing the `application permissions` and assumed that they are assigned on the level of `security group`. Only restriction happen on that level.

**Long Version**
The updated mental model looks like this: [image]

It means that the `application permissions` for `MS Graph API` are required.
The `security group` is only restricting / limiting the access to the users mentioned in the `policy`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to call /{user-id}/calendar/events to work the user must have mailbox on Exchange Online if you are using client credentials for Daemon applications.

Also, It seems assigning license to a guest account (Personal account in this case) is not possible and hence the user account never gets access to the calendar service (part of o365 exchange online) due to which it cannot retrieve the calendar information of personal account.

Please refer my answer similar to this in [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/675618/index.html?ns-enrollment-type=Collection&ns-enrollment-id=e4q5s6rym7z3m3) for detailed description.

Comment: The accounts are `work` ones, as per MS terminology. It is not a `personal` one, like xxx@gmail.com or xxx@yahoo.com.

Comment: Could you clarify this "The user id is from a personal account that I found in the Azure Active Directory details of the Azure Tenant". Also, does user have mailbox configured if account has work account.

Comment: There are many users in our tenant. Here I meant that the account is mine. I will edit the question to avoid ambiguity as my word choice overlaps with MS terminology.